# JBoss 6.1 not limiting the number of threads it launches with @Asynchronous

Tags: asynchronous, jboss, ejb, ejb-3.1, jboss6.x

Our application is launching a series of threads via the @Asynchronous annotation on EJBs. However, JBoss (contrairy to [this](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBAS-9356)) is not limiting the number of threads launched. Debugging shows that it is using a default class rather than the one configured in the XML linked in the issue above. The comment on the class says:

```
Static singleton access to a default java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService
implementation used by clients who do not supply a
org.jboss.ejb3.async.spi.AsyncInvocation to handle asynchronous
EJB 3.1 invocations.
```

So the question is under what circumstances is JBoss not supplying an `org.jboss.ejb3.async.spi.AsyncInvocation` class and how can you ensure that this does happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JBoss AS 6.1 should indeed limit the number of threads by default, but due to a bug this simply does not happen. The global setting is sadly ignored without warning.

If it doesn't concern too many beans, you can use the `org.jboss.ejb3.annotation.Pool` annotation:

```
@Pool(value = POOL_IMPLEMENTATION_STRICTMAX, maxSize = 10)
public class SomeBean {
    // ...
}
```

Be careful though, if I'm not mistaken this will create a pool per bean.

Comment: Thanks Arjan. Do you know if that bug is documented anywhere? I could not find it.

Comment: I'm not sure if its documented somewhere. JBoss AS 6.0 was end of lifed very soon after its release. The community had to scream a lot to even get 6.1 released, so bugs in 6.1 didn't got a lot of attention.